# CSS; How to make Image hover transition effects for both on AND "off" hover?

Tags: css, hover, shopify, transition

I'm editing a Shopify eCommerce theme and I want to achieve [this little "hover" effect](http://hn.arrowpress.net/franco-plus/) on images (scroll down to products, and hover over a product image)

I followed a tutorial on Shopify, and it said to implement this CSS:

```css
/* ===============================================
// Reveal module
// =============================================== */

.reveal .hidden { display: block !important; visibility: visible !important;}
.product:hover .reveal img { opacity: 1; }
.reveal { position: relative; }
.reveal .hidden { 
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;  
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;  
}
.reveal:hover .hidden { 
  z-index: 100000;
  opacity: 1;    
}
```

This code snippet worked, and the result was [something like this](https://radiance-theme-wood.myshopify.com/collections/all)

Can you see the difference? 
It's like when you move your mouse **away** there is **no transition**. I know it's possible to do because I can see it on the first link, but how? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `z-index: -1` and it will work.

The z-index was hiding the hover image behind the main image instantly so the animation is not working properly that way. Since the hover image have an `opacity` there is no need to have `z-index: -1` in this case.

Comment: Thank you! Somehow, that got it to work the way I wanted o.o
But I don't understand, how come?

Comment: @Louay Madrid You where not animating the `z-index` only the opacity. So you can remove the z-index or animate it as well. But since there is no point to it you can remove it.

Comment: Right. Note that even if the z-index had been animated in the OP's example, it wouldn't have helped much, since it is only animatable as whole values. The .hidden block would have changed from being hidden (at z-index -1) to visible (for z-indexes >= 0) instantaneously.

Comment: @Mr Lister sure I will add it. I was expecting not to work when animating the z-index, but it does when I change the transition to `all` instead of `opacity`, that's why added it as an alternative in the comment.

Comment: @drip In this specific example, the z-index would change from <0 to >=0 fairly early early in the transition (since it changes from -1 to 100000), but you can see the difference better if it would start at -100000. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/nzsv7y5x/3/) where the hover state seems to start only halfway through the transition, and the de-hover transition seems to happen only at the beginning.